# Unknown Layout in Android

Tags: android, layout

I am interested to learn how to make this Layout (in Picture):

:[image]

As you can see there are 2 Layouts and user can switch them with the button what is in upper right corner. Can someone learn me how to make this Layout?

Comment: I think [this](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) is what you're looking for.

Comment: You should use a navigation drawer with an ExpandableListView.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you using [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) library.
That is exactly what you want.

It has numerous options, so you can customize the view you want to get behind.

Answer (score 0):

i think you had to customise viewpager layout . 
set first layout width as u need to be shown.

[sample view pager](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/android-tutorial-using)

Answer (score 0):

The left menu is implemented with a library called [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu?source=c). In the sliding menu you can simply add normal layout / android ui components. So there is a ListView with items. The items are simple LinearLayouts with the correct weights, to achieve a "table like" layout. 
There are two ViewTypes in the ListView. One is a normal Item, one is a section header (Linear Layout or Framelayout).

You could also use a RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout, but Relative Layout are "more expensive" (performance) than a LinearLayout.